# grouping name together in same module group

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have a PLSQL procedure whereby i get data from two table and list the module code, name and student names who are taking the module. However, i have a question as my output currently is like this

```
BE1301 Business Analytics: Robert
CIST2013 Data Fundamentals: Henry
BE1301 Business Analytics: Betty
LS1101 Communication and skills: Aron
```

However i want it to be like this instead

```
BE1301 Business Analytics: Robert, Betty
CIST2013 Data Fundamentals: Henry
LS1101 Communication and skills: Aron
```

Below is a the procedure select statement for my output

```
create or replace procedure module groups is
modulegrp module.m#%type := -1;
 begin
  for cRow IN ( select m#,mname,studname,
                      from module left outer join student
                      on module.class = student.class
                      order by name DESC )
                      loop 
  if cRow.c_custkey is not null then
                     dbms_output.put_line(cRow.M# || cRow.mname || ':' | cRow.studname);
  end if;
  end loop;
  end;
  /
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by and `ListAgg` aggregation function in Oracle:

```
select m#,mname,LISTAGG(studname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY studname) as names 
from module 
left outer join student
    on module.class = student.class
group by m#,mname
order by name DESC
```

Comment: When i inserted the Listagg and withingroup afterwards how do i call the name in my dbms_output, i try calling it  dbms_output.put_line(cRow.M# || cRow.mname || ':' | cRow.ListAGG(studname); however it is not recognize

Comment: give it  an alias

Comment: The complete expression: `LISTAGG(studname, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY studname) AS names`. Then you can access this with `cRow.names`.

Comment: The output still lists the student one by one and doesnt group them together in one module